# magento 1.8 : how to keep Last name under First Name in billing and shipping addresses in checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, shipping, billing

How can I change the layout for the first and last name fields so that they are placed one on top of another, instead of one being next to another?
The same thing is needed for "city" and "state/province" fields.
The reason I need this is that in my russian magento, in mobile view those entry fields overlap each other which confuses the user. Thanks

Comment: Please specify your magento version.

Answer (score 0):

To change design of billing address and shipping address, you have to customize phtml file as per your design.

The first name and last name field are coming from **template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml** and this phtml file called from **template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml**.

By this two files you can adjust your billing and shipping address design.

This may help you.Thanks

Comment: Hi Prasanata. Can you tell me how to edit the phtml to relocate the "last name" and "state/province" fields so that they are in a column with everything else? Thanks you

Comment: first build static html design and then adjust that design in phtm files mentioned above.